# How to redirect mobile users to mobile version of my site?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, html

I have a website www.domain.com and I have designed a new mobile version m.domain.com. But how to detect the mobile device and redirect them to m.domain.com from www.domain.com?

Comment: Link to the duplicate would be great. Are we talking about the post from 2009? Or 2010?

Answer (score 3):

I just searched in google and here is the first result:

http://mobiledetect.net/

```
include 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect();

// Check for any mobile device.
if ($detect->isMobile())

// Check for any tablet.
if($detect->isTablet())

// 3. Check for any mobile device, excluding tablets.
if ($detect->isMobile() && !$detect->isTablet())
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for detecting mobile devices and then redirect it:-

```
<script>
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
window.location = "m.domain.com";
}
</script>
```

The `test()` method has been used to test for a match in a string and if a match is found then a redirection takes place. Add this code at the top of the page.

Comment: @ vivek and how to redirect to mobile version... it will be beetter if u can give me the whole code

Comment: @Amarjeet See my updated answer. Its just a few lines solution.

Comment: @ vivek Thanks for your help.But can you tell me with where to include in this code?and if any thing else is needed to include with this code.

Comment: You have to include this code inside <script> code here </script>

Comment: You should not redirect with JavaScript because you cannot set the proper response headers (301, 302) and that is bad for SEO. Use PHP as noted by Jari below.